# RegEx to check if a string is a number

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a value that I believe is a number, but the RegEx I am using to confirm that the value is a number is failing.

I'm not sure if it's the value's fault or the RegEx's, because this RegEx worked for me in past cases.

```
regnumber = re.compile(r"(\d),(\d) | (\d)")

print("final weight:", weight)

if regnumber.search(weight):
    print("weight = an int")

else:
    print("weight does not = int")
```

This bit of code produces:

```
final weight: 7088                   
weight does not = int
```

Can someone explain to me either why my RegEx fails or how that isn't a number?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use a comma?

Comment: If you're looking for a string of digits, use `\d+`

Comment: In the RegEx? Because sometimes I will be encountering numbers with commas so I need to take those into account too. Like `2,345`

Comment: Then you need to remove the spaces, I believe.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I added that condition into the RegEx as well, and it still says the weight is not an int...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked! Why were the spaces causing the number recognition to fail though?

Comment: Because spaces are meaningful in the regex pattern, unless you use `re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` options.

Answer (score 7):

An **integer** (integral number) is a sequence of one or more digits. So:

```
re.compile(r'\d+')
```

But in that case you do not need a regex, a simply `str.isdigit()` is sufficient:

```
if weight.isdigit():
    print("weight = an int")
else:
    print("weight does not = int")
```

A **decimal number**, can be matched with the following regex:

```
re.compile(r'\d+(?:,\d*)?')
```

So you can check the input with:

```
regnumber = re.compile(r'\d+(?:,\d*)?')

print("final weight:", weight)
if regnumber.match(weight):
    print("weight = a number")
else:
    print("weight does not = number")
```

Note that a regex will look for *any* subsequence. So `'foo123,45bar'` will also match. You can use the `^` and `$` anchors to force full matching:

```
regnumber = re.compile(r'^\d+(?:,\d*)?$')

print("final weight:", weight)
if regnumber.match(weight):
    print("weight = a number")
else:
    print("weight does not = number")
```

Like [@chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506983/regex-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number/44507054#comment76007514_44507054) says: you can replace the `,` in the regex with `[,.]` to allow the dot (`.`) to be used as a decimal dot as well.

Comment: Is a comma used for a decimal in Europe or is that a typo? Maybe `\d+(?:[,.]\d*)` would be better

Comment: @chris85: In Belgium a comma is indeed used as a decimal dot. I don't know about the rest of Europe.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem For my project scenario **isdigit** worked like a charm. Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 2):

To match digits, possible white spaces and commas you can use `r'[\d ]+(,\d+)?'`
It will also give a full match for numbers with or without comma, but no invalid comma occurrences like `,,` or `1,` or `,9`

Examples of what it will match

- 123
- 1
- 59
- 39,8
- 1 259,12312

Won't match:

- ,,
- 10,
- ,0

Comment: @chris85 True. Thanks I'm always bit too quick on regex. Updated to catch more cases and not match others

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to do it this way?

```
>>> val = 92092
>>> type(val)
<class 'int'>
>>> val = 893.22
>>> type(val)
<class 'float'>
```

Also, if you want to stay with the RegEx... Try: **(\d)+**

Comment: You can test if it's a int by doing this: if (type(val) == int): print('is int');